# AZ CLI commands fail when trigger the pipeline in GitLab with error EOF when reading a line

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli

```html
$all_repo = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $OrgUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})

foreach ($repo in $all_repo.value) {

    if(($repo.name -eq "customer-main") -or ($repo.name -eq "customer-sub")){

       $all_repoTokens=az devops security permission list --id 2e9eb000-0000-47d4-8000-0ffdd275f000 --subject $sa_username --organization https://dev.azure.com/$organization/ --output table`

       }

}
```

I have used above code in a PowerShell script of a GitLab pipeline. But pipeline fails at line 4 where I have invoked an Azure CLI command Below is the error message
[image]

I have tested above code in PowerShell & PowerShell ISE & it works properly. This error occurs only in GitLab pipeline. I couldn't find a reason for this can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

you have a "`" at the end of the line, you need to remove that

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply. I have put ` at the end because I have invoked an Azure CLI command there in a PowerShell script. I even tried removing the ` .but same error.